# how to place a time display box in a time progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have time progress bar. i use this code.i need time runner inside blue box.

how can i fix it, means when the yellow bar move depends on time need a time

display box.

[image]

```js
var timer = 0,
    perc = 0,
    timeTotal = 2500,
    timeCount = 1,
    cFlag;

function updateProgress(percentage) {
    var x = (percentage/timeTotal)*100,
        y = x.toFixed(3);
    $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", x + "%");
    $('#pbar_innertext').text(y + "%");
}

function animateUpdate() {
    if(perc < timeTotal) {
        perc++;
        updateProgress(perc);
        timer = setTimeout(animateUpdate, timeCount);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pbar_outerdiv').click(function() {
        if (cFlag == undefined) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            perc = 0;
            cFlag = true;
            animateUpdate();
        }
        else if (!cFlag) {
            cFlag = true;
            animateUpdate();
        }
        else {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            cFlag = false;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#pbar_outerdiv { cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @user6838959: Why using fiddle? SO have snippet editor too.. just clicking on `<>` button on editor toolbar

Comment: Can you perhaps try and fix up the wording here. I'm having a hard time understanding what your trying to do.

Comment: @FadhlyPermata oh thats great. thanks for that. I never noticed that in the editor :)

Comment: @user6838959: Your welcome :)

Comment: i create the using this link  http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/hnfRe/  instead of percentage but i need time

Answer (score 1):

You already have the actual time in the updateProgress() method, so its as simple as changing the line setting the percentage to this:

```
$('#pbar_innertext').text((percentage / 100).toFixed(2) + " s");
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/McNetic/hnfRe/395/

Edit: With different browser, I now see the next problem: The animation can take much longer than the advertised time of 2500 ms (because of the very high update frequency of 1000 frames per second). So you should do less animation frames and calculate the percentage base on actual time measuring, like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/McNetic/hnfRe/396/

Comment: i want only  display it in on pause time on the end of yellow time bar

Comment: @ nicolai ya i want show the time display only the pause time

Answer (score -1):

Check [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scjks0b0/1/). You can adjust the CSS: colours, sizes, etc to your needs.

Basically I put the text outside the `#pbar_innerdiv` in a `span` box.

```
<div id="pbar_outerdiv">
   <div id="pbar_innerdiv"></div>
   <span id="pbar_innertext">Click!</span>
</div>
```

**Edit**

So I edited the script and I hope now it matches your needs: [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/scjks0b0/2/). This is the script I used:

```
    var timer = 0,
    perc = 0,
    percIncreaser,
    timeTotal = 2500, //Only change this value time according to your need
    timeCount = 1,
    secondsCount=0,
    cFlag;

function updateProgress(percentage,time) {
    //var x = (percentage/timeTotal)*100;
    $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", percentage + "%");
    $('#pbar_innertext').text(time/1000 + "s");
}

function animateUpdate() {
    if(perc < timeTotal) {
        perc+=percIncreaser;
        secondsCount+=10;
        updateProgress(perc,secondsCount);
        if(perc>=100) clearTimeout(timer);
        else timer = setTimeout(animateUpdate, timeCount);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pbar_outerdiv').click(function() {
        percIncreaser = 100/timeTotal*10;
        if (cFlag == undefined) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            perc = 0;
            cFlag = true;
            animateUpdate();
        }
        else if (!cFlag) {
            cFlag = true;
            animateUpdate();
        }
        else {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            cFlag = false;
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: instead of percentage display i want a time

Comment: a countdown or counting up? @aswathy